# hidden element in protractor

Tags: protractor, hidden

Am expecting, protractor script to identify the element inside this td having element with tooltip called "Reinstall"

```
 var items = element.all(by.repeater('installation in license.devices'))

     .filter(function (item) {
          return item.element(by.binding('installation.device.host'))
                   .getText().then(function (label) {
                       console.log("Fetching Variable Value :: " + label);
                       return label === vDeviceIP; 
                       //  return label.includes(vDeviceIP);
                    });
      });

    items.get(0).element(by.css('.td [uib-tooltip*=Reinstall]')).click();
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);
```

but, when i used this script shows the error as "Element not visible"

I tried the below too,

```
  var elm = items.get(0).element(by.className('td hidden-xs'))
     .all(by.css('[uib-tooltip*=Reinstall]')); 

//items.get(0).element(by.xpath("//div[2]/xas-installation-options-app-view/div/span[1]"));

  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
```

but, not working for me.

[image: [Example]]

Can any one suggest on it?

Comment: Please show HTML in text, not in screenshot.  And the shown code in screenshot is insufficient.

Comment: Hi Yong,  I hope this is helpful<div class="td hidden-xs">

<span class="reInst" 
uib-tooltip="Reinstall" tooltip-append-to-body="true" 
ng-click="device()">
</span>

</div>